# How can I get the HTTP protocol version from AWS load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, http-headers, reverse-proxy, amazon-elb

I'm trying to build a reverse proxy behind an AWS Classic Load Balancer, and I want to use the `Via` header.

[As I understand Via](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.7.1), I should add the protocol version (eg `HTTP/1.1` or just `1.1`) to indicate the upstream client's request protocol version.

However, I don't see anywhere in the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/x-forwarded-headers.html) that the load balancer will pass that information on to my EC2 instances. Indeed, there is apparently no such thing as a `X-Forwarded-Proto-Version` header.

So how can I know the protocol version from behind an AWS Classic Load Balancer?  What about the new Application Load Balancer?  If that will do it where the Classic will not, I can upgrade.

EDIT (Apr 2019): We since upgraded to Application Load Balancer (ALB) for other reasons, and I can confirm that the ALB doesn't send the `Via` header, nor any other header that contains information about the client to ALB HTTP version. But ALB (and CLB) are a proxies and they should include the `Via` header, right?

Comment: The `Via` you add is supposed to reflect properties of the immediate request, i.e. the HTTP version sent to you by the CLB, which in turn is supposed to add `Via` with the version *it* received from *its* upstream. Do I understand correctly that you get no `Via` entry from the CLB and are trying to reconstruct it?

Comment: @VasiliyFaronov ah, yes, you're right. CLB is a proxy too, so I need to chain it.  I'll see if CLB passes through the Via and report back